Convert RTF to PDF jodconverter
I'm trying to convert RTF to PDF, but I get this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at isc.libreoffice.JODRTFtoPDF.rtfToPdf(JODRTFtoPDF.java:24)
    at isc.libreoffice.JODRTFtoPDF.rtfToPdf(JODRTFtoPDF.java:15)

Here's how I'm trying to convert:
package isc.libreoffice;

import org.jodconverter.core.DocumentConverter;
import org.jodconverter.core.office.OfficeException;

import java.io.File;


public class JODRTFtoPDF
{

    private DocumentConverter documentConverter;

    public String rtfToPdf(String filePath) {
        return rtfToPdf(filePath, null);
    }

    public String rtfToPdf(String filePath, String outputFilePath) {
        if (outputFilePath == null) {
            outputFilePath = filePath.substring(0, filePath.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".pdf";
        }

        try {
            documentConverter.convert(new File(filePath)).to(new File(outputFilePath)).execute();
        } catch (OfficeException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

        return outputFilePath;
    }
}


I understand that the error is that I didn't initialise the DocumentConverter class object. But I haven't found an example of how someone would do it.
I tried to use the code from the wiki on github:
final LocalOfficeManager officeManager = LocalOfficeManager.install();

File inputFile = new File("1.rtf");
File outputFile = new File("1.pdf");
try {

    officeManager.start();

    JodConverter
            .convert(inputFile)
            .to(outputFile)
            .execute();
} catch (OfficeException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} finally {
    OfficeUtils.stopQuietly(officeManager);
}

But there's an error there too:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 2 more


You should include the slf4j jar as a dependency so logging for the libraries works properly. The logging 'backend' probably too. You should look at the documentation to see what they use. You should be using a build tool such as Maven or Gradle

fyi this would convert your document: new ProcessBuilder("soffice", "--headless",  "--convert-to pdf", inputFilePath).inheritIO().start(); with LibreOffice installed

@g00se I added the jar file and got this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/star/lib/uno/helper/UnoUrl
at org.jodconverter.local.office.OfficeUrl.socket(OfficeUrl.java:92)
at org.jodconverter.local.office.OfficeUrl.(OfficeUrl.java:147)
at org.jodconverter.local.office.LocalOfficeUtils.buildOfficeUrls(LocalOfficeUtils.java:217)
at org.jodconverter.local.office.LocalOfficeManager$Builder.build(LocalOfficeManager.java:212)
at org.jodconverter.local.office.LocalOfficeManager.install(LocalOfficeManager.java:113)

@g00se I added the jar file... My suggestion has nothing to do with jar files ;)

That problem you're now having is down to missing dependencies. The other approach with ProcessBuilder has none

@g00se I tried using ProcessBuilder, everything works, but slowly. With jodconverter it should work much faster

The following works for me:
package com.technojeeves.jodconvert;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import org.jodconverter.core.document.DefaultDocumentFormatRegistry;
import org.jodconverter.core.office.OfficeUtils;
import org.jodconverter.local.JodConverter;
import org.jodconverter.local.office.LocalOfficeManager;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final LocalOfficeManager officeManager = LocalOfficeManager.install();
        try {

            // Start an office process and connect to the started instance (on port 2002).
            officeManager.start();
            try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Path.of(args[0]));
                    OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(Path.of(args[1]))) {
                JodConverter.convert(in).as(DefaultDocumentFormatRegistry.RTF).to(out)
                        .as(DefaultDocumentFormatRegistry.PDF).execute();
            }
        } finally {
            // Stop the office process
            OfficeUtils.stopQuietly(officeManager);
        }
    }
}

I created a Maven project with the following pom:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.technojeeves.jodconvert</groupId>
    <artifactId>jodconvert</artifactId>
    <name>jodconvert</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.1</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jodconverter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jodconverter-local-lo</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.7</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <archive>
                                    <manifest>
                                        <mainClass>${exec.mainClass}</mainClass>
                                    </manifest>
                                </archive>
                                <descriptorRefs>
                                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                                </descriptorRefs>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <properties>
            <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <logback.version>1.5.6</logback.version>
            <exec.mainClass>com.technojeeves.jodconvert.App</exec.mainClass>
        </properties>
    </project>


Bear in mind that you're not going to see much gain in just executing the process until (guessing) you reuse that LocalOfficeManager. afaics the API doesn't rely on library calls but rather on piping to a running soffice process

Well, it's really speculation [informed I hope ;) ]
